# How to get the event of Slider when pressing GamePad.A on XBox

Tags: uwp

I'm using `Slider`. When set focus the `Slider` control, press GamePad.A to select to thumb dot, the
`PreviewKeyDown` event does not fire.

So how to get the pressing GamePad.A event. I tried on desktop, it can fires this event, but not on Xbox.

```
<Slider Height="80"
        PreviewKeyDown="Slider_PreviewKeyDown"/>

private void Slider_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using `PreviewKeyUp` event.

```
<Slider Height="80"
        PreviewKeyDown="Slider_PreviewKeyUp"/>

private void Slider_PreviewKeyUp(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    
}
```